# How do i replace \\ with / in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.6, python-os

I have a part in my program that requires working with directories.My current code is:

```
path = os.path.join('C:','Users',getpass.getuser(),'AppData','Roaming','Microsoft','Windows','Start Menu','Programs','Startup')
```

Variable path prints: 'C:Users\\name\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup'.

My question is how can I make var path print 'C:Users/name/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Startup'

Comment: Why do you want to though? On Windows, ``\`` is the directory separator, and the `os.path` module does the right thing here.

Comment: yes it is correct only and replace does what you want..

Comment: Despite getting the "correct" output depending on your OS from `os.path.join` you probably also want to use [`os.path.realpath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.realpath) on your `join`ed path to avoid an error from `c:Users` instead of `c:\Users`.

Comment: @ChristianKönig Thank you,i didn't see there is a backslash missing after C: so I thought python uses / for directory operations. I always mix those.

Comment: Look for the Path class in the [Unipath](https://github.com/mikeorr/Unipath) module. It has very nice features for this kind of problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments the system does it.

You are better off changing `os.sep` or `os.path.sep` but however you can do this.

```
>>> os.path.sep = '\\'
>>> os.path.sep
'\\'              #we have changed the separator
>>> os.sep.join(['C:','Users',getpass.getuser(),'AppData','Roaming','Microsoft','Windows','Start Menu','Programs','Startup'])
'C:\\Users\\name\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup'
```

But you can simply use this though,

```
>>> '\\'.join(['C:','Users',getpass.getuser(),'AppData','Roaming','Microsoft','Windows','Start Menu','Programs','Startup'])
'C:\\Users\\name\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup'
```

Well both are the same as mentioned in the comments!.

Also `os.path.join` does not depend upon `os.sep` or `os.path.sep` so changing them doesn't prove any effect.

Comment: Please notice that `os.sep.join` is a simple `str.join` and not the dedicated `os.path.join`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.replace()` method of strings

```
"C:Users\\name\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup".replace('\\', '/')

#'C:Users/name/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Startup'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace '\\' with '/'

```
path = path.replace('\\','/')
```